# How to upload a file larger than 32MB from django admin panel hosted in Cloud Run?

Tags: python, django, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

### Problem

I need to upload zip files with a size of ~800MB to a GCP Cloud Storage bucket using Django's admin panel. My Django API is hosted in Cloud Run, and I just found out Cloud Run has a request size limit of 32MB. I want to know if there's any workaround for this.

### What I tried

I have tried using signed URLs and chunking the file in 30MB chunks, but got the same "413: Request too large" error. It seems that when I upload the file from the admin panel, it still sends a request with the whole file instead of sending it chunked. Here's my code up until now, which works perfectly from my local machine using a Cloud SQL proxy:

##### utils.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from google.cloud import storage

def generate_signed_url(file_name, chunk_number):
    storage_client = storage.Client(credentials=settings.GS_CREDENTIALS)
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(settings.GS_BUCKET_NAME)
    blob_name = f'zip_files/{file_name}_chunk_{chunk_number}'
    blob = bucket.blob(blob_name)

    url = blob.generate_signed_url(
        version="v4",
        expiration=3600,
        method="PUT"
    )

    return url

def combine_chunks(bucket_name, blob_name, chunk_count):
    storage_client = storage.Client(credentials=settings.GS_CREDENTIALS)
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)

    # Create a list of the blobs (chunks) to be composed
    blobs = [bucket.blob(f'zip_files/{blob_name}_chunk_{i}') for i in range(chunk_count)]

    # Create a new blob to hold the composed object
    composed_blob = bucket.blob(f'zip_files/{blob_name}')

    # Compose the chunks into a single object
    composed_blob.compose(blobs)

    # Delete the chunks
    for blob in blobs:
        blob.delete()
```

##### forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.conf import settings
from .models import Photoset
from .utils import generate_signed_url, combine_chunks
import requests

class PhotosetAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Photoset
        fields = ['name', 'price', "store_photo", "left_photo", "central_photo", "right_photo", "video_length", "photo_count", 'zip_file']

    def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = super().save(commit=False)

        file = self.cleaned_data.get('zip_file')
        if file:
            # Split the file into chunks
            chunk_size = 1024 * 1024 * 30  # 30MB
            chunks = [file.read(chunk_size) for _ in range(0, len(file), chunk_size)]

            # Upload each chunk separately
            for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks):
                signed_url = generate_signed_url(file.name, i)
                headers = {'Content-Type': file.content_type}
                response = requests.put(signed_url, data=chunk, headers=headers)
                if response.status_code != 200:
                    raise ValueError('A chunk could not be uploaded.')
                
            # Combine the chunks into a single file
            combine_chunks(settings.GS_BUCKET_NAME, file.name, len(chunks))

        if commit:
            instance.save()

        return instance
```

##### admin.py:

```
...
@admin.register(Photoset)
class PhotosetAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'name', 'price', 'insert_date', 'last_modified_date')
    list_display_links = ('name',)
    list_filter = ('models',)
    search_fields = ('name', 'price')
    list_per_page = 25
    form = PhotosetAdminForm
...
```

zip_file is a FileField in my Photoset model.

Comment: You're on the right track with `generate_signed_url()`, but you're using it incorrectly. Using `requests.put()` to upload the file means that your Django instance must receive the file before it can be uploaded to GCS. Instead, you should give the signed URL to the client, and have the client send the file to GCS using the signed URL.

Comment: Using `chunked` will not matter. It is the total size of the request body that determines the limitation which is 32 MB. Cloud Run is not designed for you to upload large files. There are many factors to consider, two important ones are cost (you will pay 10 cents plus per GB for egress traffic) and memory consumption (Cloud Run uses memory for temporary storage). Redesign your application to upload files directly from the client to Cloud Storage.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm tackling exactly the same issue and would love some tips on how to approach this!  I got to a similar place and I'm not sure how to run the client-side part of the code in the admin panel